# How to Include a reusable class library in AWS Lambda Function project From .Net SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

Anybody please help on the below scenario.

I have to create multiple lambda functions as per the requirement, where most of the lambda function having some common behavior like storing objects to S3, Invoking External APIs , Get Configuration keys. I am planning to add reusable class library which i can use for all  functions .What is best approach for this

Tried creating class library and added project reference to lambda function project. But want to check is this right approach

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Lambda Layers, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Sounds like that will solve your challenge